# C trimming a string with multiple words

Tags: c

Here is part of my my c program.

```
cmdline = "ls | sort -r " 
char * cmd1 = strtok(cmdline, "|");
char * cmd2 = strtok(NULL, "");
sscanf(cmd1,"%s",cmd1);
sscanf(cmd2,"%s",cmd2);
```

I am try to get the output as

```
cmd1 = "ls" 
cmd2 = "sort -r"
```

But the output I get is

```
cmd1 = "ls" 
cmd2 = "sort"
```

I found out that the sscanf function make the "-r" disappear.
But I have no idea how can I trim " sort -r " become "sort -r".
and also " sort -r -r " become "sort -r -r"

I try

```
sscanf(cmd2, "%s %s %s", cmd3, cmd4, cmd5);
```

But it cant do the trick because the number of element is fixed.

So what can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: The `%s` format with `scanf` reads *space delimited* strings, or "words". I recommend you make another function which can trim your strings (there are plenty or examples all over the Internet if you can't figure it out yourself, which is simply finding the last space character from the end, and replacing it with the string null-terminator).

Comment: You cannot modify literal strings.  They are read-only.

Comment: @SwainG These statements sscanf(cmd1,"%s",cmd1);
sscanf(cmd2,"%s",cmd2); do not make a sense.

Comment: As mentioned there are other problems with your code. First of all you have to remember that `strtok` *modifies* the string it tokenizes, which isn't possible with literal strings like you have. And secondly as mentioned your `sscanf` calls doesn't make sense. In fact using the same argument as both the source and a destination leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Thank for all comment on sscanf(cmd1,"%s",cmd1); sscanf(cmd2,"%s",cmd2);
I used to think it can work like a = a+1; with the same argument.
I will correct it now. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `strtok` you must make sure that the string you are tokenizing is mutable, as `strtok` overwrites the delimiter characters with NUL bytes, forming the tokens in existing memory.

For example, it is important to know the difference between these two objects:

```
const char *immutable = "pointer to a string literal.";
char mutable[] = "a character array, initialized by a string literal.";
```

To trim leading space, you can find the first non-space character, and move it and all subsequent characters to the front. [`strspn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strspn) (and [`strcspn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcspn)) are useful functions for finding *spans* of characters.

Alternatively, in this case, you could advance the pointer until it points to the first non-space character. This strategy doesn't work when you need to retain the base pointer, however (e.g., to pass to `free`).

To trim trailing space, you can start from the end of the string, working backwards til you find the first non-space character, and place a NUL terminating byte *after* it.

---

Here is an example of a basic trimming function.

Note that, in this example, the contents of `tokens` have the same [lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/lifetime) as `cmd`. Additionally, `trim` does not compress whitespace inside the string (e.g., `sort    -r`).

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_TOKENS 8

char *trim(char *s) {
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t ll = strspn(s, " ");

    if (ll) {
        while (s[ll])
            s[i++] = s[ll++];
        s[i] = '\0';
    } else
        i = strlen(s);

    while (i && s[i - 1] == ' ')
        i--;

    s[i] = '\0';

    return s;
}

int main(void) {
    char cmd[] = "ls |  sort -r|    foo   |   | bar ";
    char *tokens[MAX_TOKENS];
    char *tok;
    size_t n = 0;

    tok = strtok(cmd, "|");

    while (n < MAX_TOKENS && tok) {
        tokens[n++] = trim(tok);
        tok = strtok(NULL, "|");
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%zu:[%s]\n", i, tokens[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
0:[ls]
1:[sort -r]
2:[foo]
3:[]
4:[bar]
```